# how to get a list of all cameras of the user

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, adobe, camera

I want to get the list of all user cameras so that he could choose from a dropdown from which camera to broadcast

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply:

```
 import flash.media.Camera;
```

and than you can databind the dropdown to `Camera.names`

---- edit ----

Just to clear this up a bit, this kind of databinding will not find new cameras. You would actually need to get the value of Camera.names yourself when needed, to force the new search.